# inet_ntop returns 0.0.0.0 in first usage

Tags: c, linux, ip, posix, inet-ntop

I'm trying to write server application. I want to get client's ip. My problem is with inet_ntop function. I can't get it working properly. Here is my usage :

```
void client_loop(uint16_t port) {
     int cfd;
     int socket = bind_socket(port, INADDR_ANY);
     char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
     struct sockaddr client_addr;
     struct sockaddr_in *addr_in;
     socklen_t cli_len;
     while (work) {
        if ((cfd = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(accept(socket, &client_addr, &cli_len))) < 0) {
            if (EAGAIN == errno || EWOULDBLOCK == errno)
                continue;
            ERR("accept");
       }
       addr_in=(struct sockaddr_in *)&client_addr;
       inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr),ip, sizeof(ip)); 
       printf("INET_NTOP: %s\n",ip);
    }
}
```

First usage of inet_ntop always returns 0.0.0.0 Then it works properly. When im moving inet_ntop  to outside function it works properly only for  connections from localhost. Thanks.

EDIT:

Fixed. The problem was that **cli_len** wasn't initialized so accept wasn't filling **client_addr**.

With this line its working like a boss:

```
socklen_t cli_len=sizeof(struct sockaddr);
```

Comment: What does the debugger say of the contents of `addr_in` ?

Comment: An address of 0.0.0.0 means that the socket is listening on all addresses. A specific address like 127.0.0.1 would mean that the server is just listening on that address, but not on any other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i couldn't find the issue, but i see that you have given cli_len as argument, but you have to use sizeof(ip) in place of the 4 th argument (cli_len) of inet_ntop. and also please check for the cli_len also before calling inet_ntop